# XML file formatting - remove stray CRLF

Tags: xml, powershell, newline, powershell-2.0

I have an input XML file (not very big - 200) which has the odd record which is badly formatted i.e. notes which is separated by unwanted `CRLF` characters which puts onto separate lines:

```xml
<NonStandardAddress>
    <LocationId>L127755</LocationId>
    <Street>UNKNOWN</Street>
    <PostCode>U</PostCode>
</NonStandardAddress>
<Notes>
67 High Street
Newtown
Newshire
RG30 9ZA</Notes>
<StartDate>1970-12-23</StartDate>
```

[image]

It should look like this with the text in one line separated by a comma:

[image]

I was thinking doing this as a 2 step process:

1. Find all lines that are not terminated with a `>` symbol and adding the comma (this shold give me a division between each entry)
2. Replacing lines that have a comma and `CRLF` with just a comma (this should put all non matching lines back together on 1 line)

I am using PowerShell v2 btw so I cant using `-Raw` for reading in the source file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would read the XML using the `Get-Content` cmdlet and use the `SelectNodes` method with an XPath expression to retrieve all elements. Then iterate over the text and replace all `CRLF` with `,`:

```bsh
$filePath = 'your_path'
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $filePath)
$xml.SelectNodes('//text()') | ForEach-Object {  
    $_.Value = ($_.Value.Trim() -split "`r?`n") -join ', '
}
$xml.Save($filePath)
```

**Output:**

```xml
<NonStandardAddress>
  <LocationId>L127755</LocationId>
  <Street>UNKNOWN</Street>
  <PostCode>U</PostCode>
</NonStandardAddress>
<Notes>67 High Street, Newtown, Newshire, RG30 9ZA</Notes>
<StartDate>1970-12-23</StartDate>
```

Comment: Side note: Careful with the `$filepath` variable. `Get-Content` and `$xml.Save()` play in different worlds and thus have different ideas about the current directory. When calling .NET methods on paths `Resolve-Path` is often useful. Or you make a point of always using the full path everywhere. In that case it's usually best to keep the FileInfo object from `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem` around which cmdlets can accept as file paths and you can easily use its `FullName` property to pass to .NET methods.

Comment: Hi All, thanks to Martin and Joey for the comments above, As joey pointed out  I just had to tweak the filepath but its now working perfectly.